# Json to XML and XML to Json in C#

Tags: c#, xml, json

I have a large json code file whose link is : http://wikisend.com/download/365094/json_File.txt

I want to convert this code to xml and then after the xml code is generated, I want to convert the xml file back to json.

I have tried using "Jsonconvert" and many different kinds of XmlToJson codes, but I keep getting an error:

```
there are some error or array value getting null or few parameters are missing in the
converted code etc
```

What should be my approach or how can I solve it ?

Comment: "Some error" and "large file" are not making this answerable debugging question - please provide small inline sample + data. Otherwise this is exact duplicate of question you've likely seen already.

Comment: The jsonConvert is not working as its giving wrong converted output.